# JSP and JSTL conditionally render rows in table based on rule

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have the following in JSP page

```
 <table border=1>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>User Id</th>
                <th>First Name</th>                
                <th>DOB</th>                
                <th colspan=2>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.userid}" /></td>
                    <td><c:out value="${user.firstName}" /></td>                    
                    <td><fmt:formatDate pattern="dd-MMM-yy" value="${user.dob}" /></td>                    
                    <td><a href="UserController?action=edit&userId=<c:out value="${user.userid}"/>">Update</a></td>
                    <td><a href="UserController?action=delete&userId=<c:out value="${user.userid}"/>">Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<p><a href="UserController?action=insert">Add User</a></p>
```

A normal user is allowed to enter only 10 rows by clicking **Add User** button, administrator could enter any number of rows to the table.

Rows added by administrator can only be viewed by administrators and all the other rows added by normal user, but normal user cannot view rows added by administrators.

How can I conditionally render rows in JSP based on the above mentioned rule?

Thanks

Comment: if you have something like ${user.role} then you can use <c:if> to check for the role and conditionally render data

Comment: @Atrix1987 `<c:if>` will be within `<c:forEach` or I have put in for each row?

Comment: it all depends on how you want it. like you need to enable the Add User button conditionally depending on the number of rows, as you mentioned normal user can add max 10 rows, similarly for displaying rows, you can place a c:if within c:forEach to skip rows added by admins

Comment: i will post this as an answer so that you can accept it if it helps you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`<c:if>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/if.html) tag to conditionally display the data. Something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${users}" var="user">
    <c:if test="${user.role != 'admin'}">
        <!-- code here -->
    </c:if>
</c:forEeach>
```

Also i believe you will need to conditionally disable the **Add User** link if the number of users already added is 10 and the user current user is not an admin.